# How to enforce a class to implement an interface with the correct type signature for function members

Tags: typescript

I might be missing something quite obvious here, but if I do something like

```
interface ITest {
  f(a: string): number
}

class Test implements ITest {
  f() {
    return 1
  }
}
```

the compiler is perfectly happy with it, despite the implementation of `f` not having the correct signature.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you think should be a correct signature?
I tried same in typescript playground, and works fine for me too!
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20ITest%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20f(a%3A%20string)%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Test%20implements%20ITest%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20public%20f(a%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%201%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D

Comment: Your example is the correct implementation, aka the signature of the function defined in the class matches the one of the interface, but mine doesn't, some I'd like to see a compile error

Comment: Can you please update your question with some links of research you did beforehand? (SO questions, or other sites, etc) ?

Comment: Any valid input for the interface is valid for the implementing class, why would you consider the definition invalid?

Comment: @wormania because the signature is incorrect, as the interface specifies that `f` should take a single `string` parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a nutshell, this is a valid declaration for the method because it can safely ignore its parameters since they aren't used inside.

Since function signatures are always read from the caller's perspective - it will fail with the underlying JS error - i.e trying to use a non existing variable in case you would try that.

This behavior exists by design and you can read about the entire motivation around it in Typescripts FAQ page under [why are functions with fewer parameters assignable to functions that take more parameters](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters)